# How to access current Sitecore item in layout .aspx, while in preview pane in the Sitecore content editor?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, preview

I have put together an .aspx page which is the layout for a certain template. I cannot get the current item by path (i.e. by calling `Database.GetItem(string)`) while in the Sitecore preview pane, though it works fine on the web, even using the .NET `Request.RawUrl` property.

How do I most easily get access to the current item in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 Sitecore.Context.Item
```

to get the item for the current page on Preview mode and on Normal mode.

To check if you are on preview you can use :

```
if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview) and
```

if is normal page you can use :

```
   if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal )
```

Comment: Thank you for politely answering my newbie question. I am reading up as fast as I can, but am in the middle of a project where I must deliver.